# Как с помощью ajax вывести в div уже готовую переменную?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Суть такова, что есть ajax, который передаёт форму в обработчик, но я не понимаю, как результат вернуть в нужный `div`? Вот кусок ajax

```
function sendAjaxForm(result_form, ajax_form, url) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:     "/auto_sm.php", //url страницы (action_ajax_form.php)
        type:     "POST", //метод отправки
        dataType: "html", //формат данных
        data: jQuery("#"+ajax_form).serialize(),  // Сеарилизуем объект
        success: function(response) { //Данные отправлены успешно
            output = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            document.getElementById(result_form).innerHTML = output;
        },
        error: function(response) { // Данные не отправлены
            document.getElementById(result_form).innerHTML = "Ошибка. Данные не отправлены.";
        }
    });
}
```

мне нужна с файла auto_sm.php , после отправки формы, получить переменную `$output` в нужный `div`, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `console.log(response);` - ??

Comment: в чём проблема? что вы не понимаете? в `success` выпололняется что-то в случае `200` ответа. в чём проблема???

Comment: В console пусто)

Comment: Может кто за плату сделать, сколько этот кусочек кода стоить?))

Comment: переменную php нужно вывести <?php echo $output; ?>

Comment: Покажите код на php

Answer (score 1):

Igor все верно написал. Для отладки можно запихать console.log(response) в success, а если не уверены, что приходит 200, то и в error. Я бы еще поменял dataType:'html' на dataType:'json' тк мне кажется, что parseJSON не может распарсить response.
А там уже зависит от ответа. Не понятно какой формат и что вообще отдает php.

Comment: как вариант что переменная в обработчике просто нигде не выводится.

Answer (score 0):

```
    success: function(response) { //Данные отправлены успешно
        jQuery("#" + result_form).html(response);
    },
```

Comment: Не много не понял) это же мой кусок кода, как мне вывести то ?

Comment: Нет, это мой кусок кода.